# Automated trading btc-e.com?

Tags: trading, automation

Hi I'm looking for a way to make a automated trading robot. I know there is btc robot but it is too rapid, I only want to make long term trades. like making a trading robot where i can set the limit for buying and selling.
Buy when price is at 300$ and sell all my BTC when price is at 600$. maybe some alert/notification system when the price is at the "set sell price" and when the price is at "set buying price".

does anyone know such kind of trading robot?

Comment: OkCoin.com has this functionality built in in the exchange it self, I'm not very familiar with the concept but in the BTC spot you have the options to set trail orders and limit orders, perhaps you should look into that and perhaps btc-e has the same functions